# dict.setdefault appends one extra (default?) item into the value list

Tags: python, dictionary, setdefault

I am using a dictionary to group data from a CSV file, so for instance fist and second columns are the dict key and value will be a list of tuples with column 3,4.

my code snippet is:

```
import csv
import collections
csvDicData_ = dict()

fh = open('myfile.csv', 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)
for indx, row in enumerate(reader):
    if row:
        #-- put in a dictionary form: #csvDicData_[(row[0],row[1])] = (row[2],row[3])
        key   = (row[0],row[1])
        value = (row[2],row[3])
        #-- I'd like to use the row below (commented) insted of the next two, I expect the same result... 
        #csvDicData_.setdefault(key,[value]).append(value)

        if (not key in csvDicData_): csvDicData_[key] = [value]
        else: csvDicData_[key].append(value)
```

The code above produces the correct result, altough I tried to use `csvDicData_.setdefault(key,[value]).append(value)` and for some reason that I do not understand, the `len(csvDicData_[('field1x','field2x')] ))` has always one more item (with value (0,0) that expected.

Why this behaviour (it is like the first line in the CSV file for each key  automatically adds the tuple (0,0) to the dictionary/key.

Comment: `setdefault(key, [value]).append(value)` will append value to the list if it exists, but if it doesn't, first it creates a list like `[value]`, and then appends value to it. not sure why it's always `(0,0)` though, but you definitely will get an extra entry. you want `setdefault(key, []).append(value)`...  btw, using `defaultdict(list)` is an easier way to get similar functionality....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first time when you do

```
csvDicData_.setdefault(key,[value]).append(value)
```

the `key` will not be there in the dictionary and so the key will be created with the value as `[value]`. Now, `setdefault` returns the value corresponding to the `key`. So, `[value]` is returned and you are appending `value` to it. That is why you are always getting one extra element.

This should have been just

```
csvDicData_.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

now, the empty list will be returned and you will be appending `value` to it.

---

Apart from that, you might want to open the file with `with` statement, like this

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rt') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)
    for indx, row in enumerate(reader):
        ....
```

so that you don't have to worry about explicitly closing the file.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
csvDicData_.setdefault(key,[value]).append(value)
```

you initialize the list as `[value]`, if missing, and then append `value` to it, giving you `[value, value]`. What you want instead is to initialize with an empty list:

```
csvDicData_.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)
```

or use `collections.defaultdict(list)` and just do

```
csvDicData_[key].append(value)
```